# lubridate to parse date column with multiple formats AND default to last day in month

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am trying to parse a vector with two date formats, both with and without a day, so that the day defaults to the last day of the month, only if no day is provided.
I have each component working independently but can't figure out how to get them together.
Reprex is below and my desired output would be `"2006-09-30 UTC" "2005-08-23 UTC"`.

Thank you for your time and help.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Parse dates in different formats, and default to last of month if no date specified
lubridate::parse_date_time(
  c("September 2006", "August 23, 2005"),
  orders = c("my", "mdY")
)
#> [1] "2006-09-01 UTC" "2005-08-23 UTC"

lubridate::my("September 2006") %>% 
  ceiling_date("month") - 1
#> [1] "2006-09-30"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It may be be easier to create an index based on `NA` outcome when converted to `Date` with `as.Date`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
i1 <- is.na(as.Date(v1, '%B %d, %Y'))
```

Use the index in `case_when` to apply `ceiling_date` on those that are TRUE for `NA` while just apply the `mdy` on the rest of the elements

```
case_when(i1  ~ mdy(v1) %>% 
                   ceiling_date('month') -1, 
      TRUE ~  mdy(v1))
#[1] "2006-09-30" "2005-08-23"
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  c("September 2006", "August 23, 2005")
```